# Connection error in WHMCS to Virtualmin (port 10000: Connection refused)

Tags: whmcs, webmin, virtualmin

I installed Webmin + Virtualmin and made the basic configuration. I created "Server Template" with standard settings and "Account Plan" with standard settings.

After I connected the Virtualmin server to WHMCS, and when I click on the "Login to Control Panel" button, it opens the Virtualmin panel without errors.

In the settings of the hosting products, I selected the Virtualmin module and entered the name Plans and Templates.

Now when a new user orders hosting, it can not be automatically created and gives an error.

In the logs I see this:

```
Curl Error: 7 - Failed to connect to 185.***.**.41 port 10000: Connection refused
```

And the query:

```
Array
(
    [program] => create-domain
    [domain] => 
    [user] => 
    [pass] => b5Rcn******
    [email] => *****tudio@mail.ru
    [template] => Min****host Template
    [plan] => P**host Plan
    [features-from-plan] => 
)
```

What could be the problem?